Question on matching and indexing the google sheet with tables
I have a sheet which call Import which auto refresh from other data source every hours.



Question
Answer
ID




What
Cell 2
Peter


How
Cell 3
Peter


Why
Cell 8
Peter


What
Cell 5
Liz


Why
Cell 9
Liz



and I have a other sheet that look like this named Final



ID
What
How
Why




Peter





Liz






I would like to show the data on Final and look like this



ID
What
How
Why




Peter
Cell 2
Cell 3
Cell 8


Liz
Cell 5

Cell 9



I have tried to use match and index like this for the first row and they all can get the correct result
=INDEX(Import!$A:$C,MATCH($B$1,Import!$A:$A,0),MATCH($A2,Import!$C:$C,0))

However when it come to second row
=INDEX(Import!$A:$C,MATCH($B$1,Import!$A:$A,0),MATCH($A3,Import!$C:$C,0))

it return #num! and said Function index parameter 3 value 4 is out of range.
What is the error?


Here's a generalized approach which you may adapt accordingly:
=arrayformula(xlookup(E2:E&F1:H1,C:C&A:A,B:B,))



Use query(), like this:
=query(Import!A1:C, "select C, max(B) where C is not null group by C pivot A", 1)


See query().
